# FileNotFoundException in Android but File is setup properly, what is wrong?

Tags: android, fragment, filenotfoundexception

I am having a problem. When I implemented the following file in this class which when run independently seems to show the properly being read it works and saves the data into the `ArrayList`s. This the code I have for that class:

**MachineLearningInstance.java**

```
public class MachineLearningInstance {

/*
     * Setup Arraylist of Iris Items which will be the size of the .data file
     */
private ArrayList<Iris> irisData = new ArrayList<Iris>();
private ArrayList<Iris> trainingArray = new ArrayList<Iris>();
private Context context;


/*
 * These are values for the NeuralNetwork Constructor
 */
private final String comma = ",";
private final String irisSetosa = "Iris-setosa";
private final String irisVersicolor = "Iris-versicolor";
private final String irisVirginica = "Iris-virginica";

public MachineLearningInstance(File f, Context context) {

    this.context = context;

    try {

        int noOfRowsInData = 0;

        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
        try {
            lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            noOfRowsInData = lnr.getLineNumber();
            //System.out.println(noOfRowsInData);
            lnr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        irisData = new ArrayList<Iris>();

        // While there is another line in inFile.
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(f);

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfRowsInData - 1; i++) {

            if (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                // Store line into String
                String line = inFile.nextLine();

                // Partition values into separate elements in array
                String[] numbers = line.split(comma);

                // Grab values from that line and store it into a Iris ArrayList Item
                irisData.add(i, new Iris(i, numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4]));

            }
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (irisData == null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "IRIS DATA IS NULL!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < irisData.size(); i++) {
        Toast.makeText(context, irisData.get(i).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, irisData.get(i).getIrisClassName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } // Used to check values

    //sortData();

}

/*
Initialize method to grab the 2-D array of the Iris items
 */
public ArrayList<Iris> getTestData() {
    return irisData;
}

public ArrayList<Iris> getTrainingData() {
    return trainingArray;
}

public ArrayList<Iris> sortData() {

    trainingArray.addAll(irisData.subList(0, 100));

    return trainingArray;
}


}
```

When I implement the following code into this fragment, I get a `NullPointerException` which I think is being caused by a `FileNotFoundException` because I think the file is not being read properly when implemented through a fragment. Here is the code I have for the Fragment:

```
public class PredictFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView mListView;
private ArrayList<Iris> irisArrayList;
private ArrayList<Iris> trainingSet = new ArrayList<Iris>();
private ArrayList<Iris> testSet = new ArrayList<Iris>();
private MachineLearningInstance machineLearningInstance;
private IrisAdapter irisAdapter;

private FileOutputStream rawFile;
private File rawFileOutput;


/*
MachineLearningInstance to grab data from .data file and sort it into partition arraylists
 */

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.predict_listview, container, false);

    rawFileOutput = new File("C:\\iris\\iris.data");
    machineLearningInstance = new MachineLearningInstance(rawFileOutput, getActivity());

    trainingSet = machineLearningInstance.getTrainingData();
    testSet = machineLearningInstance.getTestData();

    irisAdapter = new IrisAdapter(getActivity(), testSet);

    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mListView.setAdapter(irisAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.irisclassification, PID: 1675
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at >com.irisclassification.PredictFragment.onCreateView(PredictFragment.java:59)
>               at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)

---

**EDIT:**

So would using a fileoutstream and then casting it to a file object be the best way to go about this?

I went ahead and bundles the .data file into the raw assets folder in the resources directory, would this be the correct approach to go about getting access to the .data file on the android device?

```
 public FileOutputStream createFile() {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.iris);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int size = 0;
        // Read the entire resource into a local byte buffer
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((size = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, size);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        buffer = outputStream.toByteArray();

        rawFile = new FileOutputStream("iris.data");
        rawFile.write(buffer);
        rawFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rawFile;
}
```

Comment: You are apparently trying to open a file that resides on your Windows development system: `C:\iris\iris.data`. Your Android test device does not have access to your PC's file system. On top of that Android is based on Linux. Valid file paths look different there. You need to bundle `iris.data` with your Android app, so it will be installed on your Android device. Search the Internet for Android "asset files" and "raw resources" and look for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\iris\iris.data` is not existent in Android. You have to change the path to a file that exists on your device (Reading files may need an additional permission!) or bundle it and use [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to retrieve it at runtime (like Nobu Games wrote).